# Seperate page numbers for each mission result

Tags: java, eclipse, report, birt

I have a question about BIRT reporting system. I have designed a BIRT report and it has 40 pages to print out. In this report I have mission type, mission name, mission details. Suppose that I have 5 missions in total with each of these missions are 8 pages long to read full of its details. What I want to print on top of the pages are

Page and Mission Relation:

[image]
Also while doing this iteration, normally the header rows should be printed on each page (it contains mission name, type data which changes over each mission) but instead the details are ignoring the header rows and continue going down which makes the design look bad.

As a conclusion, is there a way in BIRT that makes it understand how to separate the pages internally in each mission and how to make the header to be shown in each page.

Thank you for your answers!

(BIRT Version: Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2))

I have tried moving the whole header rows into a masterpage, which resulted in very slow response time.

I have tried a running count on page number but it resulted in counting the whole 40 pages instead of 1/8 style.

Answer (score 0):

In BIRT, page numbers can only be shown on the master page.
That's what the UI offers. But actually it is possible to move the corresponding auto-text item into a table group header cell by editing the XML directly.

Anyway, I think the "grouped page numbering" requires separate RunTask and RenderTask.

That way (and by using page variables) it is possible (but overly complicated) to achieve the desired results by putting the header rows into a masterpage.

See [How to restart page number from 1 in different group of BIRT report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29909479/how-to-restart-page-number-from-1-in-)
different-group-of-birt-report for details; user3660637's answer shows the idea using page variables, my answer describes a workaround using iText.

In contrast to the page counting, the mission "N of M" part is trivial.

BTW I don't know why putting the header row into the master page should slow down report generation!?

Comment: I followed the same steps in the link you gave me; result is.

AxisFault
 faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server.userException
 faultSubcode: 
 faultString: org.eclipse.birt.report.service.api.ReportServiceException: Error happened while running the report.
 faultActor:  faultNode: 
 faultDetail: 
 {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}stackTrace:org.eclipse.birt.report.service.api.ReportServiceException: Error happened while running the report.
And it goes like this, a very long list of redlines at the end there is this one line: Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException