# Birt group header based on page

Tags: java, eclipse, birt, page-numbering

I have a Birt report that has a group on customer ID. In the table Group Header I have two grids, one that I want displayed only on the first page for each group/customer, then on subsequent pages for that group/customer I want grid #2 displayed and grid #1 hidden.

I have tried the code listed here:

[Stackoverflow - How to restart page number from 1 in different group of BIRT report](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29945069/1585252)

But it doesn't do anything at all, I can't even print out the `group_page` variable anywhere on the actual report.

I've also tried a running count inside the group of the rows, it counts fine, but in the group header it always has `1`, never above that.