# BIRT in Eclipse 4.8 How to have multiple Page Number as Footer?

Tags: birt

Ok, I feel like I'm just going in circles without much results.
I'm trying to create a PDF report with two tables with different data sets.
What I need is each table have its own page number and total page number as footer.

So it will be 
............
l Table 1 l
l              l
l     1/2    l
............
............
l Table 1 l
l              l
l     2/2    l
............
............
l Table 2 l
l              l
l     1/2    l
............
............
l Table 2 l
l              l
l     2/2    l
............
I've put each table into separate master page, but no success.
You'd think that each Master Page will keep its own page numbers, but no.
Any guidance will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

See [How to restart page number from 1 in different group of BIRT report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29909479/how-to-restart-page-number-from-1-in-different-group-of-birt-report) for a similar question.

You can either use separate RunTask and RenderTask and page variables or you could post-process your PDF outside of BIRT.

Anyway, it is possible but a bit complicated.